# How To Read Data From Text File In HDFS Using Rhipe , R?

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs

i am new to R , Rhipe and Hadoop wanna read data from file whose contents are,

```
<Author>fallriverma
<Content>Quality hotel at great price Very clean.
<Date>Nov 25, 2008
<Rating>5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   
<Aspects>
1   8826(grat):1    
3   3(clean):1  19(price):1 187(quality):1  
0   
0   
0   
3   0(staff):1  12(friendly):1  14(helpful):1   
3   6(breakfast):1  46(free):1  333(selection):1    
0

<Author>yondaime1845
<Content>Its the best of the best for a reason One of the more affordable and better hotels in the city of seattle.
<Date>Jan 2, 2008
<Rating>5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   
<Aspects>
4   41(city):1  374(reason):1   762(seattle):1  1062(affordable):1  
0   
0   
4   1(location):1   66(park):1  143(cheap):1    186(convenient):1   
0   
0   
4   5(time):1   9(service):1    12(friendly):1  608(employee):1 
0
```

i wanna read its Author and  Aspects value like 8826 from "8826(qrat):1" and wanna display them column wise m using hadoop,rhipe and R

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i have tried this but not allow me more then one separator "ny<-read.table(pipe("hadoop dfs -cat 'new1'"),sep=">:",header=TRUE)"

Comment: new1 is my file containing data as mentioned in post

Answer (score 0):

`rhls("/user/notroot/input/")` , Give full path of your `HDFS` location- It will work